# How to put a NSMutableArray into an entity (NSManagedObject) attribute?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I defined an entity called "Map". It has three attributes:

scale : NSNumber with NSFormatter (mandatory if you want a NSNumber instead of a NSString, which >bangs<).

units : NSString

mapData : Binary Data ? Transformed value ?

This mapData attribute causes a problem. I have a custom NSView ("matrix" property) which stores some references into a NSMutableArray. This is the array I want to put into the mapData attribute. But this does not work:

```
[[[mapController arrangedObjects]lastObject] setValue:[matrix colorReference]forKey:@"mapData"];
```

Ignore everything but this :
"lastObject": is the (single) Map entity.
[matrix colorReference] is the (property) NSMutableArray.

Now, to simplify: I want the NSMutableArray to become the "mapData" attribute of the Map entity, to be stored when the doc is saved, and later retrieved and transferred to the custom view. The design is clear, the way to do it much less…

Help me, please.

Comment: I get no error, simply the NSArrayController put into then got from is <null>

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize and array and store it in Core Data by making the attribute *Binary Data* type which is basically of `NSData *` type.

Then serialize your array into NSData by using `NSKeyedArchiver`.

```
NSData *myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];
```

and back to NSArray using `NSKeyedUnarchiver`:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myData];
```

Comment: I thought Core Data was providing a serialization when setting the attribute to "Transformable", am I wrong? It works for RTFD and images, and not for an array?

Comment: If you use transformable type, you'll have to make a NSValueTransformer subclass and override the class methods to provide the conversion from an object to NSData and reverse. That's a lot more code.

Comment: Can you post your code? I'm pretty sure it works since I use it for NSDictionary myself that way.

Comment: I mean the code where you a) set your mapData and b) where you fetch and read your mapData.

Comment: That's the code. Is it that wrong? [[[mapController arrangedObjects]lastObject] setValue:[matrix colorReference] forKey:@"mapData"]; is the way I "store" in Code Data. The "lastObject" in controller is the managed object, "mapData" is its attribute.

Comment: Yes it is wrong. See my post about serializing it into NSData before assigning to Core Data attribute.

Comment: I serialized meanwhile but got -[NSManagedObject setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x105c8ad40

Comment: OK! It works. But now: when do I put the data inside the object? Is there a "aboutToSave" protocole for the document?

Comment: Ok, everything works as I wanted. Core Data DOES serialize a NSMutableArray (see my answer above).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is even more simpler, in fact.

Core Data DOES serialize the NSMutableArray into an attribute whose type is "Transformable". The transformation is of course reversible, so I can use it directly to set the property of my custom view, using just:

```
[matrix setColorReference:[[mapController content]valueForKey:@"mapData"]];
```

where "matrix" is the NSView, "colorReference" its NSMutableArray property, "map controller" the entity which stores the NSData with the key "mapData".

For the reverse operation (an edited map to save on the file), I do:

```
[[mapController content] setValue:colorReference forKey:@"mapData"];
```

As the attribute of Core Data is KVO compliant, the file is marked as edited and, of course, there is possible to undo!

For keeping references between objects (controller --> view and reverse) I simply use IBOutlet properties in my subclasses, make the bindings in IB and let the frameworks do the rest (better than I would).

Thanks!